# My ubuntu shows black screen when opened

Tags: boot, drivers

When ubuntu tries to boot, it just shows a black screen WITHOUT any kind of cursor or underscore. When I tried to open the safe mode in the latest kernel driver(4.19.045), it just gets stuck on 'Initiating ramdisk', I don't know why. However, when I open 4.19.043 kernel driver, it boots and it is completely normal. I don't know is it connected or not but when I try to update my system to ubuntu 22.10 it just doesn't and shows that it is some kind of network error. But my router is completely normal.
Version-Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Let me know if any more information is needed.
Thanks in advance.